# Google dropdownlist (select -> option)

Tags: javascript, html, web

How can i make a select-option element like this?

[image]

Comment: You should try inspecting the code and see how google do it. If you have a working sample then the best way to learn is by investigation.

Comment: Please refrain from asking this "write my code for me" type of questions. Specify the exact problem you're facing. Is it with showing a list of items upon clicking a button? With positioning the list of items? With updating the button when an item is clicked? Show us what you've tried so far, and what problems you're encountering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **not** a `select` element.

This would be a `div`, or something similar, which appears in position when a button is clicked.

To get this affect, position the element using CSS, and then use some javascript/jQuery such as:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
   $(".popup").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really investigate this yourself, especially if you have a working example like google directly in front of you.

Failing that then this article will help you:

http://theodin.co.uk/blog/jquery/fancy-select-options-jquery-css3.html

It has a full detailed explanation of how to create a fancy select using jQuery.

Always remember to fail gracefully, otherwise your website is useless to people not on the right set up. So create your html with a regular select-option so the code will work normally with a class on it (say "fancySelect"). Then in jQuery you select all items with "fancySelect" and apply the changes needed to create this new fancy select. eg parsing the options into properly styled divs and applying the javascript detailed in the link above.